# Wordpress Woocommerce - categories with different product attributes as filters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've seen this question asked a lot, but most of the answers are either commercial plugins or something obsolete.
Doesn't woocommerce have inbuilt functionality to show different attributes on different category pages that can act as filters.

I want to have a shop with 5 different categories, all with different attributes that act as filters in the sidebar.

Is there a way to solve this without buying premium addons?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on the default filter by attribute widget blocks. If you are on a category and none of the products in that category have a certain filterable attribute it won't display. Therefore you should be able to use that functionality and it will only show the applicable filters for that category. Ley me know if that works for you.

Update:
In your comments it seems you might not have understood what I meant (or I explained poorly). So here is a small walkthrough on the widget aspect of this.

WooCommerce comes with product attribute filter blocks included, you can use those to filter on any product attribute you like. Here is the setup for a site i am working on: [image]

The image contains a list of all product attributes I want to be able to filter on.  The thing is, these filters only show up if 1 or more of the products on the current product category have one of the filters attributes set up as a product attribute, this results in some categories having different filters than other simply because shoesizes are not triggered on products that feature only jackets.

This results in the following filter on category 1:

[image]

And only this 1 filter on category 2:

[image]

I think this should help you achieve what you need.

Comment: So in order to show all attributes for that category, I have to make a product that contains all the attributes?
Which widget are you talking about exactly?
I have this filter by attribute widget but it only offers to choose one attribute.

Comment: I've tried this, it's not working as it should be.
Why is this so complicated, so that premium addons can be bought?

Comment: It's so complicate because of the database structure. It's generally not recommended to save large arrays into a database as that makes it very hard to work with in MySQL. This serialization aspect has been implemented long ago in Wordpress, it was never intended to be a vast system for webshop, hence we get some designflaws that come with the legacy code.